# Two variables in echo PHP

Tags: php

I have this loop and I want to show values from question$vari2 in loop

```
            $vari1=$_SESSION['quantity'];
            $vari2=0;
            while($vari2<$vari1){
                $vari2++;
                extract( $_POST, EXTR_OVERWRITE, "question$vari2" );
                echo "<br>data1= ".$_SESSION['data1'.$vari2];
                echo "<br>data2= ".$_SESSION['data2'.$vari2];
                echo "<br>data3= "."$question1"."<br>"; //problem with this line
            }
```

How to write last line to show question1, question2 ... in loop I try `echo '$'.'question'.$vari2;` but this show $question2 in file not values of this variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely looking for [variables variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
$var = "question{$vari2}";
echo "<br>data3={$$var}<br>";
```

Comment: When I write your code i have data3= $question1 and data3= $question2 on my website not values of this variables

Comment: Indeed. Corrected.